# Python unittest testcase on catching error failing

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

So I have class Dog:

```
class Dog:

def __init__(self, res):
    self._res = res


def error(self):
    raise IndexError
```

and unit test:

```
class TestDog(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.dog = Dog([1,2])

def testError(self):
    self.assertRaises(IndexError, self.dog.error())
```

Why is the testcase testError failing? self.dog.error() should result in IndexError being rasied, and I believe the assertRaises is correctly formatted.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Python runs the line `self.assertRaises(IndexError, self.dog.error())`, it has to calculate the arguments of the method `self.assertRaises` before passing them to it, so it calls `self.dog.error()` which raises an error. This is how all functions work. The presence of `self.assertRaises` does nothing to stop the error being raised. You are meant to call `self.assertRaises(IndexError, self.dog.error)`, where the second argument is now the actual function/method object `self.dog.error` without having called it yet. `self.assertRaises` will call it for you wrapped in a try/except so that it can do the test properly.

Alternatively:

```
with self.assertRaises(IndexError):
    self.dog.error()
```